# Arrаy and string

Tags: php

How to remove comma at the end of an array?
Need output: 1,2,3,4,5 and not 1,2,3,4, **5,**

I know I can use implode, but is there another way?

```js
$massive = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 
foreach($massive as $items){
echo $items. ', ';
}
```

Comment: use function `implode()`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Print comma if you are not at the end (or, alternately, at the beginning, if you print comma before the item). But why would you not use `implode`, since it's right there, the right tool for the job?

Comment: There's a function for this - use it. If you really **can't** use it then explain **why** so that we don't spend time suggesting options that you may also be unable to use. Downvoted, because it's a meaningless question.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/tvY4L .. The most easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use implode and if don't want to use the inbuilt function then use a new variable like this

```
<?php
$massive = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$str="";
 
foreach($massive as $items){
    $str .= $items.",";
}
echo substr($str,0,-1)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern shows up frequently. I thought I might offer a generic way to handle it.

```
$arr = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600];
$out = null;
foreach ( $arr as $a ) {
    // The trick is to output the comma before each element
    // except the first one.
    if ( ! empty($out) ) {
        $out .= ',';
    }
    $out .= $a;
}
// Now I can output the string
```

What if I wanted to output the data as the loop progresses?
Just set a boolean to false then after processing the first element, set it to true.

```
$arr = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600];
$first = true;
foreach ( $arr as $a ) {
    // The trick is to output the comma before each element
    // except the first one.
    if ( $first ) {
        echo ',';
        $first = false;
    }
    echo $a;
}
```

Is there another way? Yes.

```
foreach ( $arr as $a ) {
    // see if it is the first element
    if ( $a == first($arr) ) {
        echo ',';
        $first = false;
    }
    echo $a;
}
```

Or we can detect the last item and just not output the comma.

```
foreach ( $arr as $a ) {
    echo $a;
    if ( last($arr) != $a ) {
        echo ',';
    }
}
```